# What's the 5 letter word?

Tags: riddle

I have five letters,

I am normally below you,

If you remove my first letter I am normally above you,

If you remove the first two letters I am all around you,

What am I?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are a

> chair

which is normally under you.

> hair

is normally above you, and

> air

is normally around you.

Comment: I didn't expect anyone to get it this fast, good job!

Comment: @that2guy fast because its a well known riddle

Comment: the answer was the first thing I thought about xD